# Both Chrome and Chromium log me out of everything

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

running 18.04.1 as the originally installed OS on a Dell XPS 13. Both Chrome and Chromium log me out of everything every time I restart my computer, even though I have set it to pick up where I left off when I reopen the browser, but they still remember all of my passwords. I've tried installing the repository versions, versions from the website, originally installed versions, nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that every time you reboot, your cookies are cleared?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it looks like it is. I'm not seeing any cookies on either browser that's any older than today, even though I have "Keep local data only until you quit your browser" turned off, and "allow sites to save and read cookie data" turned on.